# gSoap + HTTP Error: 400 Bad Request : Causes?

Tags: c++, web-services, gsoap, error-code

I am getting an error when i make a call like 
 soap_call__*ns2*_HelloWorld(&soap,NULL,NULL,&req,&resp)

Error 400 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
"HTTP Error: 400 Bad Request"
Detail: [no detail]

WSDL was published on a Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS, on local network and i can navigate it via 192.168.x.x/app/blabla.asmx?wsdl.

I like to know the causes of this error because i think gSoap should build xml just fine, but is my first time working with it and i dont know.

Regards,
Javi.

Comment: I can skip this problem by editing service class namespace in the webservice VS2010 project. Because i was using default: tempuri and now just work fine.!